# I can't find out what is the error in this?

Tags: java

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] tab1 = {12,134,21,23};
    int[] tab2 = {12,134,21,23};
    if(tab1 == null || tab2 == null || tab1.length != tab2.length){
        System.out.println("Differents");
    } else {
        int i = 0;
        while((tab1[i] == tab2[i]) && (i < tab1.length)){
            ++i;
        }

        if(i>= tab1.length){
            System.out.println("Equals");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Differents");
        }
    }

}

}
```

The error message is this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:14)
C:\Users\Rachid\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:    Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Hi rachid, welcome to SO. Please try to make your titles specific rather then "what is wrong with this code" and other variations of that.

Answer (score 2):

Change the loop's condition to `while((i < tab1.length) && (tab1[i] == tab2[i]))`. This way `(tab1[i] == tab2[i])` won't be evaluated when `i` is equal to the arrays' length.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception since you are incrementing your variable `i` without checking if it goes over the maximum index of your array. Then you refrence array element `i` which doesn't exist hence throwing the exception. I'd sugest adding the following line in your loop.

```
if(i + 1 > tab1.length) break;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error because your if statement disorder:

```
while((tab1[i] == tab2[i]) && (i < tab1.length)){
        ++i;
}
```

you should judge `i<tab1.length` first,like this:

```
while(i < tab1.length && tab1[i] == tab2[i]){
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: @AshwinGupta,your answer also is ok, I think our answer should explain why the questioner's problem exists and then provide our solution,your answer will be ok,but seems like you don't find out why his code causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Error happen at line `(tab1[i] == tab2[i])`. In java the array index starts at 0.
As code above:

```
tab1[0] = 12;
    tab1[1] = 134;
    tab1[2] = 21;
    tab1[3] = 23;
```

But `tab1.length = 4` when `i=4` => `(tab1[4] == tab2[4])` => ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

Coorect this line  `while((tab1[i] == tab2[i]) && (i < tab1.length) ){` as follows:

```
 while((i < tab1.length) &&(tab1[i] == tab2[i]) ){
```